# Split window.location on / and join with : if ends in / don't add :

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, indexof, window.location

I am trying to write an if statement to look at the URL and based upon what it is execute certain code blocks.  The issue I am having is with looking for when the url ends with a / and not to add a :.  For example www.site.com/folder/page/ = folder:page:  I want folder:page

```
var winLoc = window.location.href
if(winLoc.indexOf('error') > -1){
winLoc = 'Error:' + document.referrer.replace(/^.+.com/,'').split('/').join(':')
}
else{
winLoc.replace(/^.+.com/,'').split('/').join(':')
}
```

Also, I am not a RegEx person so explanations of answers appreciated :]

Comment: Simply put a `.replace(/:$/,'')` at the end?

Comment: Also, `.com` should be `\.com`.

Comment: @Xufox Easy enough - thanks.  Is there a better way of going about it or is that the best?

Comment: You could do `winLoc.replace(/^.+.com/,'').split('/').filter(Boolean).join(':');`, but I don't thinks it's necessarily "better".

Comment: @RooksStrife Posted an answer (maybe overly complex…). Hopefully, I explained everything well. And yes, I’d consider it the “best” option.

Answer (score 1):

Put a

```
.replace(/:$/,'')
```

at the end. That’s easy, intuitive and obvious, so I guess it qualifies as one of the “best” options. I think you also forgot to assign the result to `winLoc`…

I’d actually recommend reducing code repetition like so:

```
var winLoc=(~location.href.indexOf('error')
  ? 'Error:'+document.referrer
  : location.href)
    .replace(/^(Error:)?.+\.com/,'$1') // Remove URL but keep optional “Error:”
    .replace(/(?:\/)/g,':')
    .replace(/:$/,'');
```

Note that the `.` before `com` has to be escaped: `\.`.

Anyway, you can also write `/`…`\.com(?:\/)/` instead of `/`…`\.com/` if you wanna exclude a *starting* colon as well. The `(?:)` are just non-capturing groups (i. e. groups with no special meaning) that prevent JS to interpret certain parts as a comment (`//`).

### Testing snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('tester').addEventListener('change',function(){
  document.getElementById('out').value=separateURLByColons(
    document.getElementById('in1').value,
    document.getElementById('in2').value);
});

document.getElementById('out').value=separateURLByColons(
  document.getElementById('in1').value,
  document.getElementById('in2').value);

function separateURLByColons(input,fallbackReferrer){
  var location_href=input,
    document_referrer=fallbackReferrer;

  var winLoc=(~location_href.indexOf('error')
    ? 'Error:'+document_referrer
    : location_href)
      .replace(/^(Error:)?.+\.com/,'$1') // Remove URL but keep optional “Error:”
      .replace(/(?:\/)/g,':')
      .replace(/:$/,'');
  return winLoc;
}
```

```html
<div id="tester">
  <code>location.href:</code> <input id="in1" type="text" value="http://example.com/test/path/there/" size="30"/>, <code>document.referrer:</code> <input id="in2" type="text" value="http://example.com/somewhere/" size="30"/>
  <br/>
  Result: <input id="out" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following:

```
winLoc = 'Error:' + document.referrer.replace(/^.+\.com\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?/,'$1:$2')
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hG3hL2/10)

Comment: Boom goes the dynamite - thought there had to be a better way through RegEx rather than replace, split, join, replace.

Comment: Wait a second does this go beyond two levels down... www.site.com/folder/folder/folder/page/  ?

Comment: What is expected here?

Answer (score 0):

Again, it's questionable that this is "better", but it should handle what you are trying to do:

```
var winLoc = window.location;

if (winLoc.href.indexOf('error') < -1) {
    winLoc = 'Error:' + document.referrer.replace(/^.+:\/+[^\/]+\//, "").match(/([^\/]+)/g).join(":");
}
else {
    winLoc = winLoc.pathname.match(/([^\/]+)/g).join(":");
}
```

Sadly, `document.referrer` is a `String` rather than a `URLUtils` type, so you are forced to strip the file type and domain manually (i.e., `.replace(/^.+:\/+[^\/]+\//, "")`.

That regex matches the start of the string, (`^`), followed by one or more characters (`.+`), followed by a colon (`:`), followed by one or more slashes (`\/+` . . . note, the slash is escaped), followed by one or more non-slash characters (`[^\/]+`), followed by a single slash (`\/`).  This will match multiple resource types ("http", "https", "file", etc.) as well as multiple domain types (".com", ".org", "biz", etc.).

However, `windows.location` **IS** an object that comes from `URLUtils`, so you can simply reference the `pathname` property to get everything between the domain (the `hostname` property) and any parameters (the `search` property).  More on `URLUtils` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils

In either case, `"www.site.com/folder/page/"` becomes `"folder/page/"`, in the end.

After getting the directory string, you can then apply a single regex `match`, which will return all of the values that match the regex pattern that you provide.  In this case, that is `/([^\/]+)/g` . . . that means "any continuous group of one or more non-slash characters".  And, the `g` flag at the end of the pattern means that the code should capture all of those directory levels.

`"folder/page/"` becomes `["folder", "page"]`

All of those will be returned in an array, so you then just have to `join` the array elements together, and you have your string.

`["folder", "page"]` becomes `"folder:page"`

---

Now, there are a few caveats . . . some websites use some pretty strange values at the end of their search URLs that might cause unexpected results (e.g., take a look at Yahoo! redirects) and, if there is a page in the URL (e.g., "blah/blah/blah/page.html"), the page will be included in the result, as well.

Further tweaking can remove those, but, since it wasn't part of your question, I didn't go down that path.